# iPhone UIDataDetectorType not working in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have taken an `UITextView` and have written the code

```
phoneLabel = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 278, 200, 50)];
phoneLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
phoneLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
phoneLabel.editable = NO;
phoneLabel.selectable = YES;
phoneLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:19];
phoneLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
//phoneLabel.numberOfLines=1;
phoneLabel.text = @"+91 9999999999";
//phoneLabel.
[self.view addSubview:phoneLabel];
```

But the detect is not able to detect it's of type phone.

Comment: When you say the detect is not able to detect it't type of phone, what are you trying to detect? Is it the device or the OS version or the screen size?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use `UIDataDetectorType` **`None`** ? Try `UIDataDetectorType` **`PhoneNumber`**.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Replace this line with

```
    phoneLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

with..

```
    phoneLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```